# Flex Datagrid not updating

Tags: php, json, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6

The question:
I have an accordion with 3 index's, each containing a component. That component is always the same one (an ordinary datagrid). This datagrid receives his data through php and JSON.

Now when the SelectedIndex of my accordeon changes, the data in my datagrid should change.

this is the php query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM gerecht where typeID = " . $typeId;
```

where `$typeId` is the selectedIndex

```
if(isset($_POST['accIndex'])){
    $typeId = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['accIndex']);
} else {
    $typeId = 1;
}
```

Now whenever I change the accordion-index, the data stays the same. Here is my flex code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" xmlns:components="components.*" initialize="getData.send();">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <mx:HTTPService id="getData" url="http://localhost/P006_Project/Query.php" 
                        useProxy="false" method="POST" resultFormat="text" result="getPHPData(event)" />
        <mx:HTTPService id="sendData" url="http://localhost/P006_Project/Query.php"
                        useProxy="false" method="POST" result="sendData_resultHandler(event)">
            <mx:request xmlns="">
                <accIndex>
                    {accItems.selectedIndex + 1}
                </accIndex>
            </mx:request>
        </mx:HTTPService>

        <s:ArrayCollection id="acItems" source="{dataArray.source}" />
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.controls.Text;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.events.IndexChangedEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

            [Bindable]private var dataArray:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

            private function initDataGrid():void
            {
                getData.send();
            }

            private function getPHPData(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                var rawArray:Array;
                var rawData:String = String(event.result);
                rawArray = JSON.parse(rawData) as Array;
                dataArray = new ArrayCollection(rawArray);
            }

            protected function accItems_changeHandler(event:IndexChangedEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                sendData.send();
                trace(acItems);
            }

            protected function sendData_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Alert.show(event.result.toString());
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:Accordion id="accItems" creationPolicy="auto" change="accItems_changeHandler(event)">
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Frisdranken">
            <components:FULLTESTCOMP acItems="{acItems}" creationComplete="{initDataGrid()}"/>
        </s:NavigatorContent>
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Bieren (vat)">
            <components:FULLTESTCOMP acItems="{acItems}" creationComplete="{initDataGrid()}"/>
        </s:NavigatorContent>
    </mx:Accordion>
</s:Application>
```

I'm guessing something is going wrong either in:
- php receiving the selectedIndex?
- or flex is not able to update the datagrid with the new data?

Comment: Are you seeing the expected values hitting the 'getPHPData' fn? IE 'dataArray' contains what it should?

Comment: The contents of my 'dataArray' seem to stay the same all the time, so I guess the selectedIndex is not reaching the PHP-file?

Comment: Sounds like it. So the next step is to figure out whether the value is getting sent. I don't see any params being passed though. not sure if this matters.

Comment: I added a parameter (accIndex). And this one should get send every time my accordion changes index. But apparently something is still wrong.

Comment: How are you tracking 'change index'? What event are you looking at?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly: Whenever I click on my accordion (on one of the NavigatorContent), I fire an event that sends the selectedIndex of my accordion to my php script.

Comment: IIRC you may need to trap the click event for each accordion item. Is your change handler getting called?

Comment: K I managed to send my variable to my php script and it works if I show the results of my query in an Alert. But the datagrid is not being update now so I think this is the last struggle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K I finally found the solution. I was using 2 httpServices, I was alwayys receiving the data from the first one, but this one did not contain a parameter. So I merged both of them in one. Resulting in the following code: (I also added all of my other components so don't pay attention to them)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" xmlns:components="components.*">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <mx:HTTPService id="sendData" url="http://localhost/P006_Project/Query.php"
                        useProxy="false" method="POST" result="sendData_resultHandler(event)">
            <mx:request xmlns="">
                <accIndex>
                    {accItems.selectedIndex + 1}
                </accIndex>
            </mx:request>
        </mx:HTTPService>

        <s:ArrayCollection id="acItems" source="{dataArray.source}" />
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.controls.Text;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.events.IndexChangedEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

            [Bindable]private var dataArray:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

            private function initDataGrid():void
            {
                sendData.send();
            }

            protected function accItems_changeHandler(event:IndexChangedEvent):void
            {
                sendData.send();
            }

            protected function sendData_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                var rawArray:Array;
                var rawData:String = String(event.result);
                rawArray = JSON.parse(rawData) as Array;
                dataArray = new ArrayCollection(rawArray);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:Accordion id="accItems" creationPolicy="auto" change="accItems_changeHandler(event)">
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Frisdranken">
            <components:FULLTESTCOMP acItems="{acItems}" creationComplete="{initDataGrid()}"/>
        </s:NavigatorContent>
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Bieren (vat)">
            <components:FULLTESTCOMP acItems="{acItems}" creationComplete="{initDataGrid()}"/>
        </s:NavigatorContent>
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Bieren">
            <components:FULLTESTCOMP acItems="{acItems}" creationComplete="{initDataGrid()}"/>
        </s:NavigatorContent>
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Warme dranken">
            <components:FULLTESTCOMP acItems="{acItems}" creationComplete="{initDataGrid()}"/>
        </s:NavigatorContent>
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Wijnen">
            <components:FULLTESTCOMP acItems="{acItems}" creationComplete="{initDataGrid()}"/>
        </s:NavigatorContent>
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Sterke dranken">
            <components:FULLTESTCOMP acItems="{acItems}" creationComplete="{initDataGrid()}"/>
        </s:NavigatorContent>
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Tapas">
            <components:FULLTESTCOMP acItems="{acItems}" creationComplete="{initDataGrid()}"/>
        </s:NavigatorContent>
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Platos">
            <components:FULLTESTCOMP acItems="{acItems}" creationComplete="{initDataGrid()}"/>
        </s:NavigatorContent>
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Especialidades">
            <components:FULLTESTCOMP acItems="{acItems}" creationComplete="{initDataGrid()}"/>
        </s:NavigatorContent>
        <s:NavigatorContent label="Bocadillos">
            <components:FULLTESTCOMP acItems="{acItems}" creationComplete="{initDataGrid()}"/>
        </s:NavigatorContent>
    </mx:Accordion>
</s:Application>
```